# Potential memory leak in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, memory-leaks, linux-kernel

While doing static analysis of linux kernel for memory leaks, I came across an interesting scenario where i am not able to find the de allocation of a variable.
The allocation is happening in the following function(using kmalloc call) as below:

```
static int mounts_open_common(struct inode *inode, struct file *file,
              int (*show)(struct seq_file *, struct vfsmount *)){
  struct proc_mounts *p;

  //some code//
  *p = kmalloc(sizeof(struct proc_mounts), GFP_KERNEL);**
  file->private_data = &p->m;//the allocated variable is escaped to file structure
  //some code

}
```

I expect this allocated memory to be fixed at:

```
static int mounts_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    struct proc_mounts *p = proc_mounts(file->private_data);
    path_put(&p->root);
    put_mnt_ns(p->ns);
    return seq_release(inode, file);
}
```

But it seems this function is accessing the allocated variable to free some its internel members but not the variable 'p' itself.
So where is this variable's memory is freed? If it is supposed to free in mounts_release function then its a potential memory leak.

Comment: what the seq_release(inode, file); call does ?

Comment: mounts_release() function is supposed to release the memory associated with a mounted device as far as i know!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at seq_release:

```
int seq_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
        struct seq_file *m = file->private_data;
        kvfree(m->buf);
        kfree(m);
        return 0;
}
```

It effectivly does `kfree(file->private_data)`

Now, `file->private_data` is set up in [mounts_open_common](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc_namespace.c#L222) as

```
file->private_data = &p->m;
```

That's the  `p` which is `kmalloc'd` in your question.
The `m` member isn't a pointer, so that shouldn't be allowed to be freed. However, it's the 1. member of `struct proc_mounts`

```
struct proc_mounts {
        struct seq_file m;
        struct mnt_namespace *ns;
        struct path root;
        int (*show)(struct seq_file *, struct vfsmount *);
        void *cached_mount;
        u64 cached_event;
        loff_t cached_index;
};
```

So `seq_release()` performs kfree() on the address of the `m` member, that's the same address as was obtained with `p = kmalloc(sizeof(struct proc_mounts), GFP_KERNEL);`

I guess that's not very friendly to a static analyzer. But there's no memory leak.

Comment: In seq_release() function it is clearly stated that m is a pointer of type seq_file, so kfree(m) will free memory allocated by that pointer(which i think would have been allocated in seq_open() function as called by our original mounts_open_common() function) and not the parent structure proc_point as pointed by variable p.

Comment: Also linux uses container_of macro to extract the parent pointer from its child member. you can check that in generic_create_cred()/generic_free_cred functions.............

Comment: You cannot use the variable which is of type as that of 1st member of a structure and which points to address of first member of a structure to free the entire parent structure.

Comment: PurofHy No, it is not allocated in seq_open() as you suggest, please look at the 1. member of struct proc_mounts, it is *not* a pointer. Look at [line 257](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc_namespace.c#L257) where proc_mounts is allocated. Look at [line 261](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc_namespace.c#L257) where `file->private_data` is set, that is the clue. Look at `seq_open()` and see what it does when `file->private_data` is not NULL (it doesn't allocate anything). Notice how file->private_data is what is being freed in seq_release().

Comment: @PurofHy So finally `file->private` is what's passed to `kfree()`, that is the same address as was obtained on the mentioned line 257. Note also that it is guaranteed by C that the first member of a struct will have the same address as that of the struct itself. (i.e. it always has an offset of 0). The container_of macros are not used in the code here since there's no need to extract any containing structs. This only works because the `struct seq_file m` is the 1. member of `struct proc_mounts`, and thus `kfree(p)` is the same as doing `kfree(&p->m)`

Comment: On a different note, file->private_data will always be non null in seq_open function, why the developer tries to check it for null and dynamically allocate memory in case if it happens to be null?

Comment: After thinking more, it makes sense that although the type of variable `m` is `seq_file` in `seq_release` function, but it points to the address of `proc_mount` structure, which when given to `kfree()`, it gets typecasted to void *, now the entire memory starting from the start address of `proc_mount` will be freed.